# Android LoaderManager

Tags: android, multithreading

I have this code:

```
abstract class BaseLoader<T> implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
....
    @Override
    public void load() {
        loader = loaderManager.initLoader(super.hashCode() | (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), null, this);
    }
}
```

and i whant to run

```
for(BaseLoader<?> loader: loaders){
   loader.load();
}
```

where loaders size - more than 100.

I need to get the number of simultaneously running loaders should not exceed 5. How I can to implement it?

Comment: i think you need to use ThreadPoolExecutor. Never used it but it does have apis to control how many threads run at one time

Answer (score 0):

Actually i don't think you need to run loader continue 100 times , but if you need , you can try to use [CyclicBarrier](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html)

this is a reuse locking method , hope this help you